# GWT Compiler not found

Tags: java, gwt, ant, classnotfoundexception, gwt-compiler

In my Ant `build.xml`:

```
<path id="gwt.path">
    <pathelement location="gen/bin/main"/>
    <fileset dir="lib/main">
        <filename name="gin-2.1.2.jar"/>
        <filename name="guice-3.0.0.jar"/>
        <filename name="guice-assistedinject-3.0.0.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-bootstrap-2.2.2.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-bootstrap-sources-2.2.2.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-dev.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-user.jar"/>
        <filename name="javax-inject-1.0.0.jar"/>
        <filename name="requestfactory-apt.jar"/>
        <filename name="requestfactory-client+src.jar"/>
        <filename name="validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar"/>
        <filename name="validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="gwtc" depends="main-compile">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="src/main/java"/>
            <path refid="gwt.path"/>
        </classpath>

        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
        <arg line="-war"/>
        <arg value="gen/war" />
        <arg line="-logLevel"/>
        <arg value="ALL"/>
        <arg line="-optimize"/>
        <arg value="9"/>
        <arg line="-extra"/>
        <arg value="gen/staging"/>
        <arg line="-compileReport"/>
        <arg value="net.myapp.MyModule"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

When I run the `gwtc` target, I get:

```
...
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/Compiler
[java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler
[java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
[java]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
[java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
[java]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
[java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
[java] Could not find the main class: com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler. Program will exit.

BUILD FAILED
/home/myUser/MyProject/build.xml:181: Java returned: 1

Total time: 2 seconds
```

What's going on here? I'm adding `gwt-dev.jar` to my `gwt.path`, which means it should be available when the `<java>` task runs and tries to find the `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler`. So where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!